# Checking if nested element of JSON exists in ruby

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following JSON stored in the `structure` field. I want to check if the key `structure[cluster][ID]` exists with ruby within a ternary operator.

```
{
        "ID": "client DEF",
        "cluster": {
            "ID": "cluster 789",
            "flights": 4,
            "profit": 5245,
            "clv": 2364
        },
        "segment": {
            "ID": "segment 876",
            "flights": 2,
            "profit": 2150,
            "clv": 1564
        },
        "node": {
            "xpos": 1,
            "ypos": 2
        }
    }
```

Example

```
structure.has_key?(cluster.ID) ? structure["newField"] = "true" :structure["newField"] = "false"
```

Root level attributes work well with `has_key?` - I am not able to check exists on a nested level element. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the hash `#dig` method which lets you safely navigate levels of the hash. Also, instead of using a ternary, just assign the true/false value of the presence of the tested value to the `newField`, converted to a string if that better suits...

```
structure['newField'] = structure.dig(:cluster, :id).present?.to_s
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using a older version of ruby which do not have `.present?`. Is there a different method i can use? will `has_key?` work?

Comment: I was able to use `.nil?` and get through this. Thanks

Comment: `present?` is part of ActiveSupport (and thus Rails) and has been around a VERY long time.